# Unable to read json file in python

Tags: python, json

I am new to python and trying to read json file using python idle but not getting any success. Below is the code which I m using:

```
import json
filename = 'd.json'
with open(filename,'r') as f:
    hits = json.load(f)

print(type(hits))
```

Below is the error which I m getting:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\test.py", line 4, in <module>
>     hits = json.load(f)   File "C:\Program Files\Python-3.7.4\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
>     parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)   File "C:\Program
> Files\Python-3.7.4\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
>     return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "C:\Program Files\Python-3.7.4\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
>     obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "C:\Program Files\Python-3.7.4\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in
> raw_decode
>     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char
> 0)
```

Appreciate any help in this matter.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the json file is valid `json`?

Comment: @alex  its a json file but saved in notepad if that makes any difference. I attached screenshot from properties of the file for your reference.

Comment: Can you share the contents of the json file?

Comment: If you paste the content of the file here https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ and click process, does it say that the content is in valid json format?

Comment: Notepad is irrelevant. The file's _extension_ is irrelevant. Only its _contents_ matter. Please show us the contents as Arch2K requested, or at the very least run it through a JSON validator as Thaer has requested.

Answer (score 1):

is possible that there is some error inside the data of your JSON file, probably missing some of this characters " { } , : which are commonly used in json format.

Copy all your JSON data and paste it in this website: https://jsonlint.com/
then click "Validate JSON" at the bottom, it will tell you where it found errors.

I hope this helps!